# Slicing a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR and putting back together?

Tags: vhdl, slice

I have sliced a 16 bit STD_LOGIC_VECTOR into 3 parts. I want to leave the first 8 MSBs untouched and break the 8 LSBs into 2 nibbles to do some processing on them.
I can do all this and the processing is all fine but when I try to put them all together into a 16 bit STD_LOGIC_VECTOR output it just stays UUUU. is there a special way that putting it back together should go?

```
    signal fullout : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal Sbox1 : integer;
    signal Sbox2 : integer;
    signal tophalf : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal secondnibble, firstnibble : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); --break the LSH into 2 nibbles

  begin
   tophalf(7 downto 0) <= LUTin(15 downto 8);
   secondnibble(3 downto 0) <= LUTin(7 downto 4);
   -- Sbox1 <= to_integer(unsigned(secondnibble));
   firstnibble(3 downto 0) <= LUTin(3 downto 0);
   -- Sbox2 <= to_integer(unsigned(firstnibble));

  p1: process(LUTin)
  begin
  fullout(15 downto 8) <= tophalf(7 downto 0);
  fullout(7 downto 4) <= secondnibble(3 downto 0);
  fullout(3 downto 0) <= firstnibble(3 downto 0);
```

Comment: Your process sensitivity list is missing the signals that are in the process itself.  I'd suggest removing the process, you don't need it.

Comment: Sorry, there is more code. If I take the process out it work as you say but I want to do a look up table using the second and first nibble using a case statement. Then add the new second and first nibble with the top half to the fullout to drive the LUTout output port. When I put the case statement back in it needs the process back in and then the fullout does not update

Comment: As shown Russell is perfectly correct. The process sensitivity list has an extraneous element LUT and is missing elements tophalf, secondnibble and firstnibble. VHDL events drive process execution resumption, you're not paying attention to events on signals being evaluated in the process. The values can change after LUT. Ask a specific question.

Comment: if have the following code

Answer (score 0):

Always initialize outputs. In your case, its not clear that what is output, so here is my guess:

```
architecture xyz of zyx is
    signal fullout : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others =>'0');
    signal tophalf : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):= (others =>'0');
    signal secondnibble, firstnibble : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):= (others =>'0');
    .....
    begin
    ....
    end xyz;
```